# VS error for Windows phone

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone

For Windows Phone Development in VS Pro 2013 after installation option for building windows phone apps is not available but all requirements are fulfilled.

[image: These are the options I have for new projects]

Comment: And what is your question? What is the error? Your title to the question is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Expand store apps node you will see windows phone in there.  They were moved under store apps in visual studio 2013 update 2